# Magento 1.9.1.0 Special products page

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I have trying to add a page on my Magento Commerce that show all the product with a special price. I've find some scripts online, but not compatible with my version of Magento. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add the script you found online to your question

Comment: use my module code working fine: https://github.com/rvpatel/Magento-Special-Product-Module